# Openstack Nova Compute cluster

Tags: cloud, openstack, openstack-nova

how to glue multiple CPUs together, I mean How openstack achieves it. What do they really mean when they say create CPU cluster using Openstack Nova. Openstack is written in Python, Any example ( Basic one ) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's not what OpenStack does. OpenStack (and similar systems like Amazon's Web Services) runs virtual machines, it doesn't glue multiple servers together into one. An OpenStack instance cannot be larger CPU/RAM/etc.-wise than the underlying server it's running on.